# Kind of an ajax slider

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Imagine you click on Categories and go to a page like "news.php?category=2". In that page it'll show the news of the category and it has two buttons, "Previous category" and "Next category", the *href* for these buttons are "news.php?category=1" and "news.php?category=3", respectively.

I've used jQuery .load() to load from Categories to the News page and it worked perfectly.

```
$('.newstrigger').click(function() {
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #container';
    $('#wrapper').append('<div id="lastcontainer"></div>');
    $('#lastcontainer').load(toLoad);
    return false;
});
```

The problem is I can't seem to load the same page again with different parameters.

Can you guys help me?

After the load, I want to animate the content to the left (or right, depending which button the user has clicked) and make the loaded content appear from the right. That's why the title of this question has *slider* on it. No problems with this part of the code, I suppose.

**UPDATE:**
I'm currently working on it here:
[Link](http://luiscarloslopes.net/GOP2/Exemplos/exemplo2/)
This version doesn't have PHP, but you can see what I'm after. Click on "Projectos" and than on "Categoria 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really help to see the rest of your code.
it seems to me if you click twice you will have 2 divs with id=lastcontainer

also, i don't understand -- does this work once but not twice or not at all?

Comment: The code I posted is an example of what works, left the animation part out. After the animation you can't click twice. I've tried doing similar, like .load("news.php?category=2 #anothercontainer") but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know if it's possible to do that on the same page?

Comment: don't know any reason why it should not work. are you sure the problem is not multiple calls to .append("<div id=lastcontainer"></div>")?

Comment: Did some more testing and I guess you're right. The .append was causing conflict. Have to find out other way around it. Thanks for your time.